# Mongo DB escape front slash

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

If collection(Area) has template like below

```
{
  'path': '/city/area/street/house'
}
```

then how do we use like query here(how do i escape front slash)

```
db.getCollection('Area').find({  "path":/.city/area/street/house./})
```

this does not work

Answer (score 2):

`/.city\/area\/street\/house./`

`\` will escape the `/` inside regex.

Comment: db.getCollection('Area').find({"path":{'$regex':'city\/area\/street\/house'}}) this works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It worked using Regex like below and we don't need to escape slashes

```
db.getCollection('Area').find({"path":{'$regex':'city/area/street/house'}})
```

This does not work

```
db.getCollection('Area').find({ "path":/.city\/area\/street\/house./})
```

Comment: If you use `$regex`, do you still need to escape slashes?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev slashes not needed with regex but using escape slashes  also does not impact the result